# Elasticsearch nested mapping query not working- JAVA?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've set my one field to nested type. 
I followed as per this documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-joining-queries.html#java-query-dsl-nested-query

Below is the snippet

```
"price":{  
           "type":"nested",
           "properties":{  
              "activity_price":{  
                 "type":"double"
              },
              "multimedia_price":{  
                 "type":"double"
              },
              "transportation_price":{  
                 "type":"double"
              }
           }
        }
```

While performing query

```
QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("price", QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("price.activity_price", price)),
            ScoreMode.Max);
```

I get [nested] nested object under path [price] is not of nested type.

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.1.2

***I've three files to create index,mappings and to populate data:-***
**mapping.json**

```
{  
   "settings":{  
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "test_type_table":{  
         "price":{  
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{  
               "activity_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               },
               "multimedia_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               },
               "transportation_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**data.json**

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_index", "_type" : "test_type_table", "_id" : "1" } }
{"price": [{"activity_price":"100.00","multimedia_price":"10","transporation_price":"10"}]}
```

and **setup.json**

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/test_index -d @mapping.json
curl -s -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @data.json
```

Comment: Can you show what you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`  ?

Comment: Hey Val,
Please find the response of the curl command below:-

    "mappings":{ "test_type_table":{
"properties":{ "price":{
"properties":{ "activity_price":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
 "keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
 }
}
 }, "multimedia_price":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
 "keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
 }
}
 }, "transporation_price":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
 "keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
 }
}
 }
}
 },
 "title":{
"type":"text",
"fields":{
 "keyword":{
"type":"keyword",
"ignore_above":256
 }
} }} }}

Comment: There you go, if you look carefully the `price` field is not `nested`, so you must have done something wrong when creating the index. You need to wipe it and create it again with your mapping.

Comment: Hey Val, 

I've edited the contain of the post and added the contains of the files that i've used while creating index.

Please have a look.

Thanks

Comment: In ES 5, in order to create an index you **MUST** use `-XPUT` instead of `-XPOST`, your index probably wasn't created with your first command, but only when sending the second bulk command

Comment: I've updated to -XPUT and now i get below error:

   "type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [price : {type=nested, properties={activity_price={type=double}, transportation_price={type=double}, multimedia_price={type=double}}}]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your `mapping.json` file like this:

```
{  
   "settings":{  
      "number_of_shards":1,
      "number_of_replicas":0
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "test_type_table":{  
        "properties": {                  <--- this is missing
         "price":{  
            "type":"nested",
            "properties":{  
               "activity_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               },
               "multimedia_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               },
               "transportation_price":{  
                  "type":"double"
               }
            }
         }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can recreate your index using `PUT` instead of `POST`

```
# first delete your index
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/test_index

# recreate your index using PUT
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test_index -d @mapping.json
```

Comment: Thank you so much Val.

That was such a silly mistake.